# Center align content of a grid cell

Tags: html, css

I want to center align content inside a grid item, it's centered horizontally but not vertically. see on JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6zs8ydhf/

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 400px 200px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #111;
}

.item2 h1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item1">
    <h1>1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item item2">
    <h1>2 Should be at center</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item item3">
    <h1>3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven’t given any dimensions to the flex item. Try 100%

Comment: then it adds scrollbar

Comment: It doesn’t for me - it’s the item2 not the h1 that needs the dimensions and the flex.. I’m on a touch device at the moment so cannot put a snippet in an answer I’m afraid.

Answer (score 0):

here what you need, to do:

```
  .item {
  border: 1px solid #111;
   display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: so the grid item should itself be flex... any other way? As I don't want to make flex to griditem